# How to Integrate NUnit With VS 2008

Tags: nunit

Hi i created a unit test case using NUnit.When i run the test NUnit it works fine.But i need to run it by using Visual studio.So i referred the NUnit website and followed the below steps 
1)Right clicked the test project and clicked properties |Chose Debug option
2)checked the external program option and choosed the nUnit exe file.
3)And i run the test

Error i got:
Cannot start because the test project does not contain any test method.But i included 4 test methods which works in NUnit GUI.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [TestDriven.NET](http://testdriven.net/overview.aspx), a free Visual Studio add-in that allows you to run your unit tests with NUnit directly from the IDE.

Comment: Thanks Enrico I have completed the Task using TestDriven.Net

Comment: @umamaheswaran Glad I could help :) Could you please mark this as answer by clicking on the checkmark below the vote count?

Comment: Update to TestDriven.NET, it costs around 128€ to 168€. You can download an individual licence for testing purposes for free, but everything else is at it's cost. But let me tell you, it's worth it!

Answer (score 2):

Also ReSharper beautifully supports testing with NUnit!

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html

Answer (score 0):

On the Debug options tab, make sure to also set a command line argument with the name of your test assembly.